# ffmpeg trailing options with colon on windows

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I've just switched to Windows 10 Pro.

When I open a shell to use ffmpeg, any time I use an option with a colon I get an error.

for example:

```
ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 4096 -r 24 -i uncompressed.mov -c:v libx264 -b:v 40m -profile:v main -crf 31 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 192K -strict -2 -vf eq=saturation=1.3 compressed_31.mp4
```

gives:

```
[NULL @ 0000023184ac8c40] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'libx264'
libx264: Invalid argument
```

if I get rid of -c:v libx264, then I get the same error with '40m', or with 'main' etc... so it's always trying to read the argument after an option with a colon as the output file.

Is this a windows thing? All my commands work fine in a mac terminal.

I assume the answer is simple. Apologies for my ignorance. Feels like I'm misunderstanding the windows shell or ffmpeg on windows.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the colons to be a problem in this case, but you can enclose such arguments in `'...'` to see if it makes a difference (e.g., `'-c:v'`); alternatively, pass the entire command line to `cmd /c "..."`

Comment: thanks @mklement0, that did the trick